# Coordinate descent for box-constrained quadratic program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given the vector ${\bf b} \in \Bbb R^n$ and the symmetric positive definite matrix ${\bf Q} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac12 {\bf x}^T {\bf Q} \, {\bf x} - {\bf b}^T {\bf x}\\ \text{subject to} & \bf 1 \le x \le u\end{array}$$ Applying a coordinate descent algorithm, assume that the current solution is $\hat{x}$ and the next coordinate to update in the algorithm is $i$. Give an expression for the next iterate.

Comment: Solve the single dimensional unconstrained problem and project to the interval $[l_i,u_i]$.

Comment: @copper.hat So what i did was to take derivative:

$\nabla f(x) = Qx-b = 0$ hence, $x=Q^{-1}b$

But im not too sure how to find the derivative with respect to $x_i$, i.e.
$\nabla_i f(x)$

Comment: It is coordinate descent, so if you are at $\hat{x}$ and the direction is the $i$th coordinate then you need to minimise $\phi_i(t) = f(\hat{x}+t e_i)$, where $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x^T Xx - b^T x$. This is a quadratic in one variable and minimisation is straightforward.

Comment: I don't see any $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Could you elaborate more? How you use this specific notation?

Comment: @Royi I do not understand your question. Elaborate what?

Comment: @copper.hat, In your notation the derivative is given by $ \phi' \left( t \right ) = \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}^{T} \boldsymbol{Q} \boldsymbol{e}_{i} + t \boldsymbol{e}_{i}^{T} \boldsymbol{Q} \boldsymbol{e}_{i} - \boldsymbol{b}^{T} \boldsymbol{e}_{i} $. Now what? What do you mean to minimize with respect to $t$? Like a directional derivative?

Comment: @Royi If you set $\phi_i'(t) = 0$ you will get a formula for $t$, and you then project $\hat{x}_i+t e_i$ onto $[l_i, u_i]$.